# How to write log messages in a separate file in Python?

Tags: python, logging

Currently I am using the `print` function to write log messages:

```
print("...creating new data...")
```

(I am using the docker image `tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7` to run my service).

But in the standard log I can see only the last few messages. I want to archive my log messages over days and month.

How is it possible to write a message in Python in a separate log file?

Comment: Docker writes a container log file of everything going to stdin or stderr.

Answer (score -2):

You can use logging. Here an [example](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file)